# Correlated time-series

Tags: time-series, correlation

First, I would like to apology if my vocabulary is not correct. I am not statistician (and not mother tongue English speaker either).
So here is my problem :

For n subjects I got 8 values (human pressure at 8 different times). I would like to know if my n subjects are presenting the "same pattern" ( i don't know which word to use ... are they all correlated?)

Here is what I did (and would like to know if it is statistically correct)

for each couple of subject (so sum(1:n-1) couples) I am computing their correlation. And with this sum(1:n-1) correlation values I am running a multiple comparison permutation t-test.
If the p-value < 0.05 I consider that they are following "the same pattern".

I know that there is a problem of dependence. But, I cant see how to do it in an other way. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should research repeated measures, which is an ANOVA model that would be very useful for your data.

Comment: There is also a whole pool of methods for covariance matrix estimation. For example, described and implemented here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/covariance.html

Answer (score 2):

The data you have is sometimes referred to as panel data. Th statistical problem is NOT whether or not they are correlated BUT whether or not a similar model/set of parameters is appropriate for the individual n series . Thus in general we may have and we may wish to find what subset series have a common model. You can refer to Pooled Cross-Sectional Time Series. At the end of the day, you would estimate parameters of a suitable ARIMA model locally and also globally and construct an F Test to challenge the hypothesis of a common set of parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices. I am trying to follow them but get a problem. 
I am currently using ARFIT matlab toolbox (but I think my problem would be the same with an other program).
 It seems that it is not possible to get a global fitting of my 16 subjects and 8 time points by subject. Indeed, the fact that i get more subjects than number of time points is problematic. Is it true?

Do you have some other advices? thanks a lot for your help